# How to grep for start-string, ignore everything in middle till end-string, then concat new-string after end-string?

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

Long file, looks like this now.

```
   'blah': blah
},
'blah': {
  'blah': 'name',
  'blah': _t(`Course name',
  'blah': true,
  'blah': _t(`Machine Learning'
},
```

I want it to look like this:

```
   'blah': blah
},
'blah': {
  'blah': 'name',
  'blah': _t(`Course name`),
  'blah': true,
  'blah': _t(`Machine Learning`)
},
```

I want to find the lines with **`` _t(` ``** and find the ending single quote, erase that single quote and replace with **`` `) ``**

Answer (score 1):

`sed` should help:

```
sed 's/_t(`\(.*'"'"'\)/_t(`\1`)/g' test_file.txt > result_file.txt
```

Comment: Take care on not confusing single quote `'` and back tick `\``, neither you, nor the shell. It's always a headache.